# My Function isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to hide the chatname `div` and when hidden put the `chatid` at the bottom that's where the `64px` for but its giving me a error saying

> `toggle 3();` not defined

```
 <div id="chatdiv">
    <div id='chatid' onclick="toggle3();">
        <div id="chatname">
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

---

```
var toggle3 = function() {
var mydiv3 = document.getElementById('chatid');
var mydiv4 = document.getElementById('chatname');
if (mydiv4.style.height === '0px' || mydiv4.style.height === '' )
mydiv4.style.height = '516px';
mydiv3.style.top = "64px"

else
mydiv4.style.height = '0px'
mydiv3.style.top = "auto"

}
```

Comment: You are missing brackets around the body of the `if` - you CANNOT have `if` followed by two lines, followed by `else` without putting brackets there. Other than that, where is `toggle3` defined? it seems the HTML does not have access to it.

Comment: you need brackets `{}` around each block of the `if` `else`. Like this `if(..){...} else {...}`

Comment: Put your function inside `<script>` tag.I mean where is your `<script>` tag?

Comment: The browser console is telling you about your syntax errors.  Always check the browser console first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure but it seem you want to do this

```
  <div id="chatdiv">
     <div id='chatid' onclick="toggle3();" >
        <div id="chatname">
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

```js
var toggle3 = function() 
{
console.log(this.id);
var mydiv3 = document.getElementById('chatid');
var mydiv4 = document.getElementById('chatname');
if (mydiv4.style.height === '0px' || mydiv4.style.height === '' )
{
mydiv4.style.height = '516px';
mydiv3.style.top = "64px"
}
else
{
mydiv4.style.height = '0px'
mydiv3.style.top = "auto"
}
}
```

javascript code should enclosed by script tag other then if there are multiple expression in if else block you must have to use code block.

Answer (score 1):

As the people mentioned in the comments on your question, your code has quite some syntax errors, those things you should be able to see in your Console of the browser, where it would say that on this line something is wrong. A more correct verison of your code is the following

```
'use strict';
var toggle3 = function() {
  var mydiv3 = document.getElementById('chatid');
  var mydiv4 = document.getElementById('chatname');
  if (mydiv4.style.height === '0px' || mydiv4.style.height === '' ) {
    mydiv4.style.height = '516px';
    mydiv3.style.top = "64px";
  } else {
    mydiv4.style.height = '0px';
    mydiv3.style.top = "auto";
  }
}
```

In case you have more than 1 statement inside an if block, you would always need to create a block around the statements using `{ // code statements here ... }`

```js
'use strict';
var toggle3 = function() {
  var mydiv3 = document.getElementById('chatid');
  var mydiv4 = document.getElementById('chatname');
  if (mydiv4.style.height === '0px' || mydiv4.style.height === '' ) {
    mydiv4.style.height = '516px';
    mydiv3.style.top = "64px";
  } else {
    mydiv4.style.height = '0px';
    mydiv3.style.top = "auto";
  }
}
```

```css
div { padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }
#chatdiv {
  background-color: red;
}
#chatid {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
 <div id="chatdiv">
    <div id='chatid' onclick="toggle3();">
        <div id="chatname">
          Name
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

However, what you need might be a lot simpler to do? Why not set a class on the parent div and hide your elements based on that parent class? No need to play around with heights and other things, just change the class of the parent div, and then the resulting height/width/visibility changes can just be handled by the css changes

```
function toggle3( sourceElement, classToToggle ) {
  var target = document.getElementById( sourceElement );
  target.classList.toggle( classToToggle );
}
```

```js
function toggle3( sourceElement, classToToggle ) {
  var target = document.getElementById( sourceElement );
  target.classList.toggle( classToToggle );
}
```

```css
.active-chat-box {
}
#chatid.active-chat-box {
  height: 516px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.active-chat-box > #chatname {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatdiv">
  <div id='chatid' class="active-chat-box" onclick="toggle3('chatid', 'active-chat-box');">
    <div id="chatname">
      Name
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```